# What's the meaning of "%evp" in a PGN comment?

Tags: pgn

Example:

```
{[%evp 0,17,14,14,14,-25,-15,-15,7,7,55,48,48,48,472,228,802,802,804,771]} 
1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Bc4 Qh4+ 4. Kf1 Bc5 5. d4 Bb6 6. Nf3 Qg4
```

What's the meaning of these numbers when used together with `%evp`?

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! I guess it's related to [`%eval`](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/21786/7297). Any idea which program generated this PGN file?

Comment: the PGN is from Chessbase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question was asked by GM Tony Kosten on the [chesspub forum](https://www.chesspub.com/cgi-bin/chess/YaBB.pl?num=1543899946/24) back in January:

> Looking at the last set of PGN files I received, at the beginning is a
>   new tag followed by lots of numbers, like:
>
> {[%evp
>   0,96,30,30,22,1,30,2,2,-9,-3,-44,23,23,21,32,41,37,44,23,22,18,26,11,22,
>   -4,0,-1,8,7,7,14,9,5,16,8,38,16,22,19,25,54,19,19,22,22,22,20,20,20,24,-18,24,
>   -53,-53,-61,-61,-56,-23,-20,41,41,39,39,35,30,44,44,33,50,70,70,75,75,75,75,75,
>   56,60,59,62,56,68,56,50,48,48,40,46,60,49,30,48,47,47,59,46,56,57]}
>
> I assume ChessBase 15 generates this when it quickly analyses games
>   when you open them. However, is this a standard PGN code, can other
>   chess programs read it?

The original PGN standard was created and published in 1994 by Stephen J Edwards. Here is a copy of his original standard: [Portable Game Notation Specification and Implementation Guide](http://www.saremba.de/chessgml/standards/pgn/pgn-complete.htm). By 2001 he had dropped out of the project when [this supplement](http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/palview/enhancedpgn.htm) was published to the PGN standard. There it defined a new embedded command string which would be marked by a starting "[%".

> 3.2 A generalised format for embedding commands in comments.
>   3.2.1 Position
>   An embedded  command may occur at any position in a standard PGN comment, ie  between { } . For example: {Optional leading
>   comments [%clk 1:05:23] optional trailing comments} where  [%clk
>   1:05:23]  is the embedded command string.
>
> 3.2.2 Structure The command string is structured as follows.
>
> A leading tag of [% A command name consisting of one or more
>   alphanumeric characters. A space character. Either a single parameter
>   or a comma delimited list of parameter values. A closing tag of ]

So, "[%evp" is an embedded command, first seen in Chessbase 15 output. As such it is Chessbase 15-specific until such time as Chessbase publish how they use it, at which time other pgn producers/consumers can start using it too.

My speculation, FWIW, is that it is part of Chessbase's "Chess Position Trainer" and is intended for Chessbase internal use only.